# Commit a variable to the next function

Tags: python, django

I just simple want to pass the emailadress from `def send_username` to the second `def username_is_send`. How do I do it? How can I pass the variable to the next `def`?

```
@csrf_protect  
def send_username(request, template_name='auth/user/registration/send_username_form.html',
    email_template_name='auth/user/registration/send_username_email.html',
            send_username_form=SendUsernameForm, post_reset_redirect=None):  
    if post_reset_redirect is None:  
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('auth.user.registration.views.username_is_send')  
if request.method == "POST":  
    form = send_username_form(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
           opts = {}  
           opts['use_https'] = request.is_secure()  
           opts['email_template_name'] = email_template_name
           opts['request'] = request
           form.send_mail_now(**opts)  
           return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)  
else:  
    form = send_username_form()
return render_to_response(template_name, {  
     'form': form,},    
context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def username_is_send(request, template_name='tmp/username.html'):  
    return render_to_response(template_name, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks!

Craphunter

Comment: There is a "format as code" button in the tool bar, select your code and press it.

Comment: have you not received any help on this site?  you haven't accepted a single answer and so we have to assume that you've never been pleased with a response you've received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the state somehow in order to pass parameters through a redirect. Multiple possibilities:

1. Store the mail address in the session, then read in the session variable again in the `username_is_send` view.
2. Use a GET parameter to pass the mail address.

And it's "pass", not "path". And the "def" is called (view) function.